# Validate input date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Fecha del evento</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtfec" name="txtfec" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want to validate it so that I can only enter any dates 20 days after the current date for example.

```
date today    Date save
2016/11/29   2016/12/19
```

Comment: Adjust layout to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date format would be yyyy/mm/dd

1. Add +20 to system date and convert the date to time(t1)
2. Convert user input(i.e date) to time(t2)
3. if t2 > t1 then input is greater than 20 days else its not

Answer (score 0):

- I think date picker plugins may solve your problem
- https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: link is highly discourage, please provide information about this link